# Why does `peek` with a polymorphic Ptr return GHC.Prim.Any when used with a bind?

Tags: pointers, haskell, ghc, ghci, parametric-polymorphism

Using the [low-level GNU Science Library bindings `Bindings.Gsl.RandomNumberGeneration`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bindings-gsl-0.2.1), I'm running into this odd type behavior in GHCi where binding changes return type from a `peek` into `GHC.Prim.Any`. I'm trying to understand why since I can't use the `c'rng_alloc` unless I retain the type of pointer to an `rng`. For eample:

```
λ> :t c'gsl_rng_alloc
c'gsl_rng_alloc :: Ptr C'gsl_rng_type -> IO (Ptr C'gsl_rng)
λ> :t p'gsl_rng_mt19937
p'gsl_rng_mt19937 :: Ptr (Ptr gsl_rng_type)
λ> :t peek p'gsl_rng_mt19937
peek p'gsl_rng_mt19937 :: IO (Ptr gsl_rng_type)
λ> x <- peek p'gsl_rng_mt19937
λ> :t x
x :: Ptr GHC.Prim.Any
λ> c'gsl_rng_alloc x

<interactive>:421:17:
    Couldn't match type ‘GHC.Prim.Any’ with ‘C'gsl_rng_type’
    Expected type: Ptr C'gsl_rng_type
      Actual type: Ptr GHC.Prim.Any
    In the first argument of ‘c'gsl_rng_alloc’, namely ‘x’
    In the expression: c'gsl_rng_alloc x
λ>
```

Trying to explicitly specify the type of the peek return that doesn't help either:

```
λ> x <- (peek p'gsl_rng_mt19937) :: IO (Ptr gsl_rng_type)
λ> :t x
x :: Ptr GHC.Prim.Any
```

Comment: Note that `gsl_rng_type` here is just a type variable, so `p'gsl_rng_mt19937` has the type `Ptr (Ptr a)` and your attempt is  the same as saying `x <- (peek ...) :: IO (Ptr a)`.

Comment: @hammar I see I was confused between the type variable `gsl_rng`_type and the type `C'gsl_rng`. I'm new to haskell and not familiar with how bindings-dsl generates FFI code. How do I go about passing the value of gsl_rng_type to the alloc function. In C, it looks like `gsl_rng *rng = gsl_rng_alloc(gsl_rng_mt19937)`.

Comment: I'm guessing you'll need to cast the pointer. Have a look at the [`castPtr`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Foreign-Ptr.html#v:castPtr) function.

Comment: Could you add an answer?

Comment: @dfeuer unfortunately I still don't understand what it means for `peek` to return `GHC.Prim.Any`. But I was able to get the GSL bindings to work by using castPtr doing  `(castPtr p'gsl_rng_mt19937) :: Ptr (Ptr C'gsl_rng_type)`. Also unfortunately I came to a realization that bindings-gsl is slow as molasses for my needs. I think this is because of the lack of unsafe calls when the code is generated by bindings-dsl.

Comment: When you do `x <- peek (ptr :: Ptr (Ptr a))` in the ghci prompt, the type variable `a` must be instantiated to some concrete type. This is because the do notation `x <- peek p` means `peek p >>= \x -> ...`, where `..` is what you type into ghci afterwards. Since ghci can't know the future, it has to "cheat" during typechecking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand somewhat on @user2407038's comment:

> When you do `x <- peek (ptr :: Ptr (Ptr a))` in the GHCi prompt, the type variable `a` must be instantiated to some concrete type. This is because the `do` notation `x <- peek p` means `peek p >>= \x -> ...`, where `...` is what you type into GHCi afterwards. Since GHCi can't know the future, it has to "cheat" during typechecking.

Recall that in `peek p >>= \x -> ...`, the right-hand argument to `>>=`, namely the lambda abstraction `\x -> ...`, [is monomorphic in its argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley%E2%80%93Milner_type_system#Let-polymorphism). This is why GHCi has to assign a monomorphic type to `x`.

`GHC.Prim.Any` is the placeholder type that GHC uses in situations like this where a concrete, monomorphic type needs to be assigned to something that has no other constraints.